# javascript window.location code explanation

Tags: javascript, html, url

Can someone explain to me this code snippet?

```
 <button id="btn6"  href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="function1()" type="submit">Get Link</button>
    <script>
        function function1() {
        var Link = 'https://google.com';
          var referr = '';
        {       
                window.location = Link+''+referr;
            } 
        }
    </script>
```

I want to find the complete URL(with parameters) that is sent to the browser when clicking the button

Comment: That code does not look well written at all. `href` is not a valid attribute on a `<button>`. There is a variable that is just the empty string, even though used right after. If there is no `<form>` element around this button, its `type` is useless.
The final URL for the redirect is `https://google.com`

Answer (score -1):

As Andy said, there is a lot of issues with your code but once you fix it, use the `URL` object that is provided in modern browsers and the `searchParams` function :

```
    var url = "https://google.com/test.html?a=1&b=test-param-sample-123"; //for exemple
    var url = new URL(url);
    var b = url.searchParams.get("b");
    console.log(b);                    //return the b parameter "test-param-sample-123"
```

I let you check [this article](https://javascript.info/url) for more informations